# How to get list of google Calendar events in ios sdk?

Tags: iphone, google-calendar-api

I want to show list of google calendar events in ios sdk.

Means i want list of dates & events name from my google calendar.

Answer (score 1):

In Gdata api u have sample code chek it and use it.

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/